# Linq Query not working as expected

Tags: c#, linq

```
        string[] words = { "apple", "banana", "mango", "or", "pas", "grae" };

        var result1 = words.TakeWhile((word, index) => index > word.Length ).ToList();
```

I am learning Linq and I am trying to get all the words where the index is grater than the length of the word.

For some reason I am getting empty list. index of or, pas, grae is more than the length. But I am not getting the results. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `Where()` - `TakeWhile()` will stop iteration the first time the predicate evaluates to false (as the name might suggest), which is the case on the first word for you, hence you got an empty list.

```
var result1 = words.Where((word, index) => index > word.Length)
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
var result1 = words.Where((word, index) => index > word.Length ).ToList();
```

instead.

TakeWhile will select elements from the list while condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can learn the basic skills from 101 Linq samples here:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b/viewsamplepack